# How to get rid of "allow <website> to run 'silverlight'?" alert on firefox using firefoxprofile in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

While using robot api's to drag and drop my mouse positions are being disturbed(running firefox in full screen mode) by an alert which asks "Allow  to run silverlight?". Even my webdriver api's are getting affected due to this alert as the click intended to happen on one button performs on another.

I am using WebDriver to automate my scenario, combined with robot api for drag and drop. Is there a way i can set something in firefox profile so that this alert won't appear?

Below image shows the alert

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B36CJTZFg52aUFhvWmZIVzNleEk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new firefox profile

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

By opening firefox profile manager, and pressing add profile button and you can name it. Than you need to open that profile in FireFox, download Silverlight plugin, install it, and go to firefox plugins manager

https://helpdesk.contentraven.com/hc/en-us/articles/201455107-Mozilla-Firefox-and-Silverlight-Plug-In

in manager you will have to set silverlight plugin as Always Activate.

Then you have to just call this profile when you are invoking driver:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile your_profile = profile.getProfile("<name of your profile>");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(your_profile);
```

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question.. What he is asking, is to set the profile preference in such a way that the **Silverlight plugin** doesn't come in the way of automation.

Comment: Yes, and always activate option on custom profile will prevent it to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked for me, but Subh got my question right. I wanted something similar to this "profile.setPreference("browser.fullscreen.autohide",true);", which will set the Silverlight addon to always activate.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can do:

```
// Enable Silverlight
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.npctrl", 2);
```

And on OSX:

```
// Enable Silverlight
profile.setPreference("plugin.state.silverlight", 2);
```

On Windows, the DLL name is npctrl.dll, so I believe that's where the 'npctrl' comes from.  You can see this from:

```
about:plugins
```

For Linux you will have to check.  Open two tabs one for:

```
about:addons
```

And the other for:

```
about:config
```

In about:addons enable the Silverlight plugin to be Activated Always.

In about:config filter by 'plugins.state'.  The item that changes when you change the activation state in about:addons is the one you add to add to the FireFox profile.

Comment: Thanks watssonmw. Your answer is really helpful. I want to add something more for windows platform here. Hit about:config in firefox, you will see all plugins with state like plugins.state.<pluginName>. You only need to pick the whole name as it is(plugins.state.<your plugin Name>) and put that in below code as 1st argument profile.setPreference("1 args", 2);